# Sum or Product of Rationals with Spire (how to get a scala.Numeric)

Tags: scala, math, numerical-methods, spire

I thought this should be straight forward:

```
import spire.math.Rational

val seq  = Vector(Rational(1, 4), Rational(3, 4))
val sum  = seq.sum      // missing: scala.Numeric
val prod = seq.product  // missing: scala.Numeric
```

I guess this is just a question of bringing the right stuff into implicit scope. But what do I import?

I can see that in order to get a `RationalIsNumeric`, I have to do something like this:

```
import spire.math.Numeric._
implicit val err = new ApproximationContext(Rational(1, 192))
implicit val num = RationalIsNumeric
```

But that just gives me a `spire.math.Numeric`. So I try with this additionally:

```
import spire.math.compat._
```

But no luck...

Comment: OT: what are you using spire for?

Comment: I'm doing rhythmical (musical) calculations. Musical durations are usually expressed as rationals, so you need to be able to mangle those :) E.g. given a rhythmic cell with relative durations of 3, 2, 1 and a total duration of 1/2, calculate the individual durations, find some stretch factors which lead to small denominators etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All that's needed is evidence of `spire.math.compat.numeric[Rational]`:

```
import spire.math._

val seq = Vector(Rational(1, 4), Rational(3, 4))
implicit val num = compat.numeric[Rational]  // !
seq.sum     // --> 1/1
seq.product // --> 3/16
```

Answer (score 7):

It's also worth noting that Spire provides its own versions of `sum` and `product` that it calls `qsum` and `qproduct`:

```
import spire.implicits._
import spire.math._

Vector(Rational(1,3), Rational(1,2)).qsum // 5/6
```

Spire prefixes all its collection methods with `q` to avoid conflicting with Scala's built-in methods. Here's a (possibly incomplete) list:

- `qsum`
- `qproduct`
- `qnorm`
- `qmin`
- `qmax`
- `qmean`
- `qsorted`
- `qsortedBy`
- `qsortedWith`
- `qselected`
- `qshuffled`
- `qsampled`
- `qchoose`

Sorry I came a bit late to this, I'm new to StackOverflow.